# Microsoft Word suddenly won't save files; "word could not create the work file - check the temp environment variable"

Tags: encryption, ms-word, ms-office, environment-variables

My brand-new install of Word 2007, which had been working just fine, suddenly refused to save any files.  I'd hit Ctrl-S, and it wouldn't complain but it wasn't saving.  Then upon exiting, Word would ask if I wanted to save.  I'd click on Yes, and the same pop-up would appear, endlessly, until I chose Cancel.  Also, on opening files, Word gave an error message about not being able to access a TEMP file.  Exact wording: "word could not create the work file - check the temp environment variable".

Comment: Please read [the help](http://stackoverflow.com/help). This has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: Sounds like this question and answer would be a good fit for the www.SuperUser.com site on the StackExchange network instead of StackOverflow.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder and nvuono: I was just trying to help people.  It took me an entire day to figure this out.  There are _hundreds_ of posts on the web asking about this problem, and there are _dozens_ of horrible "solutions" that could totally screw up a person's computer, weren't applicable to me, and probably don't help anyone.  I think my answer here is the best one on the whole stinkin' web, and unavailable anywhere else.  But you guys are welcome to move it.  Or delete it, if you don't care about those hundreds of poor souls who can no longer save their Word documents.  It's your karma.

Comment: @user2654818: And posting it *to the correct site* might help people better. You have the power, right now, to move it to the correct location. I voted to move it, but I alone can't (which is how it should be).

Comment: The "correct" site of SuperUser did not come up on my Google search when I was trying to solve this problem.  In contrast, several posts on this site gave me useful hints that eventually helped me to a solution.  So, I posted the solution here.  But I will move it.

Comment: Anybody else find it ironic that this closed-for-being-off-topic question now has almost 4000 views on this site?  If you want to like it, go to http://superuser.com/questions/650764/microsoft-word-suddenly-wont-save-files-word-could-not-create-the-work-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched all over, including stackoverflow, and nothing people said to do was the problem.  But they did cause me to look at the folder C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office (where of course MyUserName is my user name).  The folder was encrypted.  I decrypted it, and -- bingo! -- Word worked perfectly again.

This was on a 3-year-old laptop with a fresh disk re-image (OS=Win7) from the helpdesk at work.  The weird thing is, that folder is encrypted on my desktop at work, and everything works fine there.

Since I couldn't find this solution anywhere, I figured I'd post it to stackoverflow.  This fix is so easy that people may as well try it before any of the other proposed fixes.